# C++11 std::generate and std::uniform_real_distribution called two times gives strange results

Tags: c++, c++11, random, stl

calling std::generate algorithm from the STL two times on different containers produces equivalent results.

Consider I want to fill up two float arrays with random numbers between -1. and 1. :

```
std::array<float, 1000> x;
std::array<float, 1000> y;

std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937_64 gen(rd());
std::uniform_real_distribution<float> dis(-1.f, 1.f);
auto rand = std::bind(dis, gen);
std::generate(x.begin(), x.end(), rand);
std::generate(y.begin(), y.end(), rand);
```

You can test it here : http://ideone.com/X712IU. Both arrays are filled up with the exact same values :

```
0:  -0.411968,  -0.411968
1:    0.55158,    0.55158
2:    0.69889,    0.69889
3:  -0.901328,  -0.901328
4:  -0.556142,  -0.556142
5:  -0.798431,  -0.798431
6:  -0.570874,  -0.570874
7:   0.928999,   0.928999
8:   0.118056,   0.118056
9:  -0.655123,  -0.655123
```

Now if I make a new generator between the generates it works ok :

```
std::array<float, 1000> x;
std::array<float, 1000> y;

// Generators in different scopes, OK
std::random_device rd;
{
  std::mt19937_64 gen(rd());
  std::uniform_real_distribution<float> dis(-1.f, 1.f);
  auto rand = std::bind(dis, gen);
  std::generate(x.begin(), x.end(), rand);
}
{
  std::mt19937_64 gen(rd());
  std::uniform_real_distribution<float> dis(-1.f, 1.f);
  auto rand = std::bind(dis, gen);
  std::generate(y.begin(), y.end(), rand);
}
```

Gives :

```
0:   0.391496,   -0.64993
1:   0.429592,   0.835015
2: 0.00735116,    0.77657
3:  -0.548355, -0.0794801
4:  -0.312095,  -0.119841
5:   0.931296,   0.997449
6:  -0.934924,  -0.832223
7:   0.432267,   0.181224
8:   0.942709,   0.165024
9:   0.315852,  -0.654576
```

And now with the same generator using for loops, it works as well :

```
// Both arrays assigned in the same loop, OK
for(size_t i = 0; i < x.size(); ++i)
{
  x[i] = rand();
  y[i] = rand();
}

// Arrays in separated loops, OK
for(size_t i = 0; i < x.size(); ++i)
  x[i] = rand();

for(size_t i = 0; i < y.size(); ++i)
  y[i] = rand();
```

It looks like something related to std::generate, but I can't find out what would cause this behavior.

Any explanation ? Cheers

**EDIT:**

As pointed out by dotcavader, the issue comes simply because the generator object has been copied (both by std::bind and std::generate). Hence the generator start with the exact same internal state for both generate.

Just to complete the answer, Praetorian and Casey gave two easy solutions for this :

Using std::reference_wrapper to store a reference in the bind instead of a copy :

```
auto rand = std::bind(dis, std::ref(gen));
```

Using a lambda that returns a reference :

```
auto rand = [&](){ return dis(gen); };
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe what's happening here is that std::generate takes its generator argument by value. As soon as you pass it in, it's copied. That means what happens inside std::generate does not affect the function object you passed in.

So you call generate again, and you copy the same generator function object, which then starts generating with exactly the same state including (somewhere inside there) which ever seed was used to initialise the number generation.

If you create a DIFFERENT generator function, even with the same parameters, you must get a different random seed inside of it. This is how your other methods are generating different results. Ultimately, their generators start with a different seed.

Comment: `std::bind` is making the first copy - but essentially you are correct.

Comment: @Casey Well yes, what's being copied is the result of std::bind. This is what I'm calling the generator.

Comment: Oh yeah, there are actually 2 copies. Never though about that, tired :)

Comment: +1 to avoid this you can pass the generator object wrapped in `std::reference_wrapper`

Comment: @ThePluc There are actually 4 instances of `mt19937_64`: `gen` on the stack, a copy inside of `rand` (the result from `std::bind`), a copy passed to the first `std::generate` and a copy passed to the second `std::generate`. The easiest fix is probably to capture the original generator by reference in a lambda `[&](){ return dis(gen); }` and just let that lambda be copied freely.

Comment: Why isn't it that calling `rand()` a few times changes its internal states, and when it's passed to the second `std::generate`, those changed changed states are also passed along with it?

Comment: The answer would be even better if you added the fixed code.